# MemoryError with large data frame in deep learning

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, deep-learning, bigdata, graph-theory

## Preamble

Hi all,

I'm trying to make a geometric deep learning model using [`StellarGraph`](https://github.com/stellargraph/stellargraph) package. With smaller data set, it works well, but unfortunately it's not scalable to a larger data set. Information on machine, environment, used data and resulting error presented as follow.

Machine specification:

- CPU: Intel core i5-8350U
- RAM: **8GB DDR4**
- SWAP: 4 GB + 4 GB (Divided into two swapfiles in different SSD)
- SSD: 250 GB + 250 GB (2280 and 2242 NVMe)

Environment:

- Linux 5.3.11_1 64-bit
- Python 3.6.9

Used data (size acquired from `sys.getsizeof()`):

- Sparse block diagonal matrix (shape: 158,950 x 158,950; size: 56)
- Dense feature matrix (shape: 158,950 x 14,450; size: 9,537,152)

Modules:

- `networkx 2.3`
- `numpy 1.15.4`
- `pandas 0.25.3`
- `scipy 1.1.0`
- `scikit-learn 0.21.3`
- `stellargraph 0.8.2`
- `tensorflow 1.14.0`

## Problem description

I aim to create a geometric deep learning to categorize subject based on adjacency matrices acquired from resting state functional MRI. Adjacency matrix assumes 55 region of interest, resulting in 55x55 matrices for all subjects. In constructing the deep learning model, I used spectral graph convolutional network model from `StellarGraph`, which take a graph object and nodal feature as its input. I created the graph object from sparse block diagonal matrix obtained by combining adjacency matrices from all subjects. While nodal feature is the characteristic of each node (1 node has 5 characteristic values), constructed into dense block diagonal matrix.

Previously, I made the model using a subset of population sample (around 170). It ran perfectly, and I thought I'd be able to do the same using larger data set. Unfortunately, using the same code I got a `MemoryError` when registering the `StellarGraph` object. Code and error presented on following section.

## Code and error

```
# Data parsing with scipy.io as sio and pandas as pd
data = sio.mmread('_data/sparse.mtx')
feature = sio.mmread('_data/sparse-feature.mtx')
feature = pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(feature)

# Create graph object using networkx as nx
g = nx.from_scipy_sparse_matrix(data)

# Create StellarGraph object and its generator
gs = StellarGraph(g, node_features=feature) # MemoryError
generator = FullBatchNodeGenerator(gs)
```

I'm sorry for not providing `sparse.mtx` and `sparse-feature.mtx` file due to confidentiality reason, but I hope previous description on data shape and size may help you to understand its construct. Using above code, python gave me following error:

```
>>> gs = StellarGraph(g, node_features=feature) # MemoryError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/lam/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/stellargraph/core/graph.py", line 786, in __init__
    super().__init__(incoming_graph_data, **attr)
  File "/home/lam/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/stellargraph/core/graph.py", line 381, in __init__
    node_features, type_for_node, node_types, dtype
  File "/home/lam/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/stellargraph/core/graph.py", line 216, in _convert_from_node_data
    {node_type: data}, node_type_map, node_types, dtype
  File "/home/lam/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/stellargraph/core/graph.py", line 182, in _convert_from_node_data
    data_arr = arr.values.astype(dtype)
  File "/home/lam/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5443, in values
    return self._data.as_array(transpose=self._AXIS_REVERSED)
  File "/home/lam/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 822, in as_array
    arr = mgr._interleave()
  File "/home/lam/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 840, in _interleave
    result = np.empty(self.shape, dtype=dtype)
MemoryError
```

While monitoring memory consumption, I observed that the RAM only used up to 55% of its total capacity,  and the swap was not used at all. While running the code, I only used TTY + `tmux` with only `vim`, `top` and `python` session running. Moreover, I also made sure no other memory-hogging processes running in the background. So I'm certain the memory bottleneck is most likely caused by `python`.

## What I have tried

To leverage the memory consumption, I tried to use `dask` in managing the dense `feature` data frame. Unfortunately, `StellarGraph` function can only have pandas array, pandas data frame, dictionary, tuple, or other iterable as its input.

Other than `dask`, I also tried using sparse matrix (since almost 80% of my data set is zero-valued anyways). However, it gave me `TypeError` since `StellarGraph` could not have sparse matrix as its `node_features`.

I've also read several solutions in managing large data set, which (mostly) suggest iteratively parsing the data into python session. However, I couldn'tgr find any documentation in `StellarGraph` on such method.

The other option would be using computer with better hardware, which to my regret, I couldn't do due to limited funding. I'm a student and couldn't afford buying better machines for now.

## Potential solution

- Upgrading the RAM. I'll try salvaging RAM from other computers, but current max size I have would be 16 GB. I'm not sure it will be enough.
- Use smaller chunk of `feature` data set. I managed to go by this solution, but the model's accuracy was really bad (50-ish %).

## Questions

1. Why `python` only use 55% of my total RAM without dynamic swap allocation?
2. How should I effectively manage large data frame?
3. How do I handle `MemoryError` when creating a `StellarGraph` object?
4. How much RAM do I actually need? Would 32GB suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python works fine. It's a implementation problem caused by StellarGraph.

I think StellarGraph so far doesn't support huge matrix.

```
File "/home/lam/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/stellargraph/core/graph.py", line 182, in _convert_from_node_data
data_arr = arr.values.astype(dtype)
```

From the beginning of your code to here, all of your data is stored as sparse array, which doesn't take too much memory. Here, arr is supposed to be a DataFrame with columns as pandas.SparseArray. This line of code converts the data structure to normal numpy array, which crash the memory usage.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.empty((158950,14450),float)
print(a.nbytes/2**30)
17.112698405981064
```

An empty numpy array here actually takes 17 G memory. I can initialize 3 array like that one on my 16 G computer. Then I get memory error if I try to get more than 3. And I can't initialize a 158,950 x 158,950 numpy array.

Comment: Hi, thank you for testing the memory issues and confirming limitations on StellarGraph. Yes, it is unfortunate StellarGraph does not currently support sparse matrix as an input. Is there a way to perform batch model training to leverage memory consumption?

Comment: Which learning algorithm do you want to run here? Maybe you can switch to another open source library.